# Area is not Working in Asp dot net Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, view, area

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihQuV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQTWD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9C4v.png)

https://localhost:7082/EmpList/EmployeeData/Index
when request pass the "return View()" then it can not identify view page and i want "localhost:7082" show then show the Index page directly . but i does not work

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your images and found that you have hard coded the end points with EmpList. Instead that you should do the following

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute("area", "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

And then in controller, you need to specify the area like below. This single configuration will work for multiple areas

```
[Area("Products")]
public class ProductController: Controller
{
}


[Area("EmpList")]
public class EmployeeDataController: Controller
{
}
```